# WebSocketTransport not available in Class Library (Portable)

Tags: c#, wpf, websocket, uwp

I am trying to figure out why NuGet is not downloading the correct version of `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client`.
To make this as easy as possible to understand, here are my projects:

1. A WPF project, targeting .NET 4.6
2. A UWP project, targeting .NET 4.6 according to the new project dialog
3. A Class Library (Portable) project, targeting `.NET 4.6` and `Windows Universal 10.0`, according to the "Targets" property.

All 3 projects have the NuGet package `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client`, and both the WPF and UWP project have the class `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Transports.WebSocketTransport` available. If I copy the class created in the WPF project to the UWP project, it finds all the references and it doesn't give me any error; however, if I try to do the same to the Class Library, it fails to find the WebSocketTransport class.

If the Class Library project has the same target as the UWP project, why isn't the WebSocketTransport class available?

**Class Library (Portable) project.json:**

```
{
    "supports": 
    {
        "net46.app": {},
        "uwp.10.0.app": {}
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client": "2.2.0",
        "Microsoft.NETCore": "5.0.0",
        "Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility": "1.0.0"
     },
     "frameworks": {
         "dotnet": {
            "imports": "portable-net452+win81"
        }
    }
}
```

**Universal Windows project.json:**

```
{
    "dependencies": 
    {
        "Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client": "2.2.0",
        "Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform": "5.0.0"
    },
    "frameworks": 
    {
        "uap10.0": {}
    },
    "runtimes": 
    {
       "win10-arm": {},
       "win10-arm-aot": {},
       "win10-x86": {},
       "win10-x86-aot": {},
       "win10-x64": {},
       "win10-x64-aot": {}
    } 
}
```

Is there any way I can make the Class Library project download the NuGet package that contains the WebSocketTransport method? The SignalR hub I need to use allows only WebSockets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to "hack" this by using the AutoTransport class, which seems to have chosen the WebSockets transport correctly upon contacting the Hub, otherwise it would have failed to connect:

```
await connection.Start(new AutoTransport(new DefaultHttpClient()));
```